# how to properly remove files added under "My Project" in solution explorer?

Tags: vb.net

I deleted the file Form1.vb on folder/explorer because I accidentally created it under MyProject in the solutions explorer. but when I tried to rebuild it I'm having below error already.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Unable to create a manifest resource name for "My Project\Form1.resx". Could not find file 'C:\Users......\My Project\Form1.vb'.

Comment: Only delete files from "Solution Explorer" (View => Solution Explorer) within Visual Studio - not from Windows File Explorer. Either recover your file from the Recycle Bin or start over by creating a new project.

Comment: but how do you delete items under "MyProject"?

Answer (score 0):

all data of  files is stored in the solution itself, Go to Solution Explorer, Select the file
Either
1.) Right click the folder, Click Delete, Confirm Deletion Process if prompted.
2.) Left click the folder and hit the Delete key on your keyboard.
Do either of these will remove it from your solution and thus, the project. If you have folders being sync'd with git hub it will also update it this way, don't just straight up delete folders from the actual windows explorer though, this could cause pointer issues for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I created same file with same filename confirmed to replace this with the missing.
then added it again on "MyProject". Project -> Show All Files from the main menu.

I think what I needed was just the Project > show all files.

thank you to everyone who answered above it made me search for this